# Reusable widget in Flutter / Dart for data with same attributes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom table widget, that has a property of type `List` holding items with certain properties.

```
final List<Item> items;
```

Where each of the items can have properties like "name", "street", "number" etc. This list is passed to the constructor.

Since i have now another class that should use the same widget again, i want to decouple it from the "Item" class itself. Instead i think its a good idea to define the properties that should be displayed in the table itself as a contructor argument instead binding it to a certain class, which isn't really flexible

The question is, how can i pass a list of "named" properties to the constructor, without using a class/data container?

so i need something like

```
List<[name, street, number]>
```

So i wanna force the caller to input a list, where each of the described property in the list has a value. So i can iterate over this and create rows

But this seems not to exist. Is there a way to do this in flutter? Or even a more flexible way where the caller can pass a variable count of data to display?

Comment: See [Records](https://dart.dev/language/records) and [Patterns](https://dart.dev/language/patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dart 3.0 feature RECORDS:

```
void main() {
  List< ( {String name, String street, int number} )  > items=[];
  var x=(name: 'Joe', street: 'street A', number: 111);
  print(x.name); //Joe
  items.add(x);
  items.add((name: 'Anna', street: 'street B', number: 222));
  print(items); //[(name: Joe, number: 111, street: street A), (name: Anna, number: 222, street: street B)]
  var y=items[0];
  print(y);//(name: Joe, number: 111, street: street A)
  print(y.street);//street A
}
```

Comment: `List< ( {String name, String street, int number} )  > items=[];` what was i was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice. I was in need to refresh my knowledge about dart 3, so it was useful for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maps:

```
List <Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
{ 'name': 'James', 
 'street': 'example',
 'number': 1 },
{ 'name': 'Mark', 
 'street': 'example2',
 'number': 2 },
];
```

Then call a variable like this:

```
print(items[index]['name']);
```

In my example, name, street and number are all strings. If you want to call different types, you just need to redefine your map to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This does not prevent that the "caller" using not predefined keys, or does it?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean but it works just like Apprendendo's answer, just differently written :) his is a list of ({}) which also represents maps

Comment: Yes, but your definition just restricts to `List <Map<String, dynamic>>` but not to a concrete key/value structure that has to be fulfilled from the "caller" side, or do i miss something? I mean in your example i could also set the list as `{'alias' : 'James'}` instead of `{'name': 'James'}` which might be unexpected in the receiver method/function

Comment: Oh i see what you mean now, yes you're correct, the caller side doesnt know the key/value structure that has to be fulfilled. Its something you would have to remember instead. In this case Apprendendo has the best answer :) thanks for the insight

Comment: Thanks for your possible solution too, even if in my case, the other one was preferred ;)